# 7%9 is showing different answers when using integer and float format specifiers. Why is it so?

Tags: c

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d \n", 7%9); //integer result
    printf("%f", 7%9); //float result
    return 0;
}
```

Above is the code I used to calculate the value of 7%9. I wanted to see both the integral and the float result. But, the values appearing here are different.

Comment: 7%9 is still an int operator and then that int goes onto the stack for printf and then printf thinks it's a float

Comment: I remember seeing this *exact* question with the *exact* same code just a few hours ago. And I'll give you the same comment I posted to that: `7 % 9` is an ***integer*** operation with an ***integer*** result. You can't print integers with the floating-point format `%f`.

Comment: Did u see the changes in values when using the int format specifier vs float Format Specifier ?

Comment: For floats, you must use `fmodf`, `7` and `9` in your case are still **ints** thats why you are allowed to use the `%` operator. Instead, try with `7.0f % 9.0f`

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type (like using the floating-point `%f` format to print an `int` value) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). The actual output is irrelevant.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't there some gcc compiler warning/error flag that reports this aberration?

Comment: @Fe2O3 the standard options (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) should be sufficient. With "standard" meaning "the options everyone should use anyway"

Comment: @Fe2O3 It depends whether the compiler (and standard library headers) have support for checking `printf` arguments or not (for example GCC/glibc uses special attributes on the function declarations in the headers to mark them as "printf-like"). There is no standard requirement to produce a warning for the UB.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d \n", 7%9); //integer result
printf("%f", 7%9); //float result
```

Although the comments and the `format specifiers` indicate your intent, the compiler sees the `integer` calculation and passes an `integer` value to printf().

In the 2nd line, you've effectively written:

```
printf( "%f", 7 );
```

That is obviously incorrect.

If you wanted to see lots of zeros, you could `cast` the value to match what you've written as the format specifier:

```
printf( "%f", (float)( 7 % 9 ) );
```

Comment: Or preferably `(double)( 7 % 9 )` since the `float` value will be converted to `double` anyway by  the *default argument promotions*.